How to copy/edit a leadgen form without losing it's linked data with Facebook API?
In my application I want users to edit their leadgen forms. As far as I know there is no possibility to edit a leadgen form. Simply creating a new leadgen form with the desired changes would result in losing linked data, such as leads.
Therefore, via the UI (Adsmanager) one would copy the leadgen form and make the desired changes which keeps the linked data (leads).
I was wondering if there is a [leadgen_form_id]/copy endpoint? Or how can I edit a leadgen form without losing linked data.
